# Electrum I requested wrong amount QR code but paid larger amount from luno?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, electrum, receiving

I requested "Receive" bitcoin on Electrum and mistakenly entered my amount in "mBTC" instead of "BTC". (My first time) I then scanned the QR code with LUNO under Send bitcoin. It gave me the incorrect BTC amount (not realising it was because I entered in mBTC in Electrum) so I corrected it on LUNO and clicked send. Now electrum says under the mBTC transaction "PAID" but its not the full amount. Under the bottom left corner BALANCE it says "0" but with the correct amount in brackets saying (0.01... UNCONFIRMED). Does this mean the funds will still find their correct wallet destination even though the QR request scanned was for the wrong amount?

Answer (score 1):

In Bitcoin, the sender chooses the amount to send. Because you corrected the amount in Luno and the correct `0.1` amount is showing (although currently unconfirmed) in electrum, you know this is the balance you will receive once the transaction is confirmed.

To understand why it is currently unconfirmed, see [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)